# Merge tables from the same database by id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 1 database with 3 tables that contain different information about the same subject as so:

table1:

```
ID  |  name  | address
-------------------------
1   |  Jhon  |  somewhere
2   |  James |  somewhere-else
```

table2:

```
ID  |  last_name  | status
-------------------------
1   |  Doe  |  single
2   |  Bond |  married
```

and I want to merge them into a new table like so:

new merged table:

```
ID  |  name  |      address    | last_name | status
----------------------------------------------------
1   |  Jhon  |     somewhere   |     Doe   |  single
2   |  James |  somewhere-else |     Bond  |  married
```

Comment: Use Joins. 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a basic join:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.name,
    t1.address,
    t2.last_name,
    t2.status
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Strictly speaking, if a given `ID` could be present in one, but not both, tables, then you might want to use a full outer join, to always present partial information, wherever possible.  If this is your case, then comment and different query can be given here.

Comment: I haven't checked your solution yet, but table1 is always the full one with all the ID's and table2,table3 might not have all the ID's. your solution should work still?

Comment: Yes, in this case you should use a _left_ join from table1 to table2.

Comment: just to make sure cause I'm not so good with SQL, after this query table1 will be updated with all the new information? (sorry for asking too many questions :) )

Comment: No, that won't happen, and that is not how a select works.  You might want to review a good SQL tutorial if you have further doubts after reading my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD COLUMN `last_name` CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD COLUMN `status` CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';

UPDATE table1 AS a, table2 as b
SET a.last_name = b.last_name
a.status = b.status
WHERE a.ID = b.ID;

DROP `table2`;
```

Comment: alias in UPDATE works just fine in mysql 5.x and up. What version are you using?